# place a labels text as straight html in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I tryed this

```
CABC</td><td valign="top"><span class="progressBar pb3">document.getElementById('<%#Label8.ClientID%>').innerHTML</span></td></tr>
```

I want to use this jquery script, basically i am using it as a sales goal progress bar, where the number before the span is the current sales. But my issue is my sales are going to be in asp.net labels not in plain text. when i tried putting my label in place of the actual number it would not work any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var progress_key = '<?= $uuid ?>';

            $(document).ready(function() {

            maxValue3 = $('#<%= label4.ClientID %>').html(); 
            maxValue4 = $('#<%= label5.ClientID %>').html();
            maxValue5 = $('#<%= label6.ClientID %>').html(); 

            $(".pb3").progressBar({ max: (parseInt(maxValue3)), textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );
            $(".pb4").progressBar({ max: (parseInt(maxValue4)), textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );
            $(".pb5").progressBar({ max: (parseInt(maxValue5)), textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );



        });
    </script>

                                    <div class="contentblock" style="font-family: Arial">
                                <br />
                                Daily Sales Goal<br />
                                <br />
            <table border="0">
                <tr><td colspan="" valign="top">
                    CABC</td><td valign="top"><span class="progressBar pb3">document.getElementById('<%#Label8.ClientID%>').innerHTML</span></td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top">
                    ABCD</td><td valign="top"><span class="progressBar pb4">400 </span></td></tr>
                <tr><td valign="top">
                    WTV</td><td valign="top"><span class="progressBar pb5">500 </span></td></tr>
            </table>
            </div>
```

and the plugin is jquery-progress-bar

Comment: not rly sure what the question is... can u elaborate more?

Comment: yeah the issue is that the jquery plugin uses the number before the span to display my progress bar, but my data is coming from a database and being stored in a label and i want to use the integer from the label instead of the number 300 so it will update dynamically

Comment: can you show us what your markup is that the plugin is reading?

Comment: did you put alert to see if you are getting right values from label in javascript? Or any js errors? Which it this plugin, can you share the link?

Comment: no i didnt do that could you tell me how sorry im a noob

Comment: document.getElementById('<%#Label8.ClientID%>').innerHTML needs to be under script tag. open up your page in chrome/firefox and check the log on developer tools, you should be able to see where exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing quotes in your example?

```
document.getElementById('<%#Label8.ClientID%>').innerHTML
```